# Event is null even object is not disposed

Tags: c#

When I call `ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView()` through COMMAND, event throws ObjectNullException. I'm thinking that Object is not dispose as its assined to `CurrentViewModel` property.

Both `GetReport()` and `ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView()` functions called by Command which are binded to Buttons. I'm pretty sure that `GetReport()` function is called first so that object is created before raising the event.

What am I missing here?

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel{

    public ViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void GetReport()
    {
        inventoryReportViewModel = new InventoryReportViewModel();
        inventoryReportViewModel.OnStatusChange += Event_OnStatusChange;
        CurrentViewModel = inventoryReportViewModel;          
    }
}

public class InventoryReportViewModel : InventoryBaseViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler<StatusChangeEventArgs> OnStatusChange;

    private void ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView()
    {
        OnStatusChange(this, new StatusChangeEventArgs("test",10));
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

XAML;

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" Margin="20 10 20 0"></ContentControl>
```

Comment: Not sure why it's null, but you should always check if an event is null before calling it.

Comment: When are `GetReport` and `ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView` being called?

Comment: @juharr I deleted it on purpose to check the problem

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov They are both called by command which are binded to buttons

Comment: @onurfoca So you had a `null` check before and it just wasn't calling your `Event_OnStatusChange` method?

Comment: @onurfoca Can it be so that the button bound to `ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView` is clicked before button bound to `GetReport`?

Comment: @juharr is correct. Please verify that you're following the pattern from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines

Comment: @juharr yes there is null check and because event seems null, event is not firing

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov no it cant as getreports is actual view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that problem occurs because of the explicit definition of the viewModel in XAML. I remove the lines below and now I can get the right object as viewModel. (I'm defining VM it in DataTemplate)

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:InventoryReportViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any subscribers before raising the event:

```
private void ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView()
{
    if (OnStatusChange != null)
        OnStatusChange(this, new StatusChangeEventArgs("test", 10));

    //or simply: OnStatusChange?.Invoke(this, new StatusChangeEventArgs("test", 10));
}
```

Then you should atleast get rid of the exception.

Since you haven't showed us how and where the `GetReport()` method is called, or any other details, it is impossible to say why there are no subscribers by the time the `ShowRevertInventorySignDialogView` method gets called.

Comment: both methods called by commands which are binded to buttons. I know that I need to check for any subscribers, I have deleted for testing purposes.